# build structure with many arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, structure

I have 21 arrays, divided by the alphabet (artistaA, artistaB etc) for the artist, and 21 for the title.
I would like to build a unique array based on a structure named VociMontagna but I'm getting an error. My target is to crate this big array and then generate a TableView based on this one in order to use the filter.
I have more than 800 titles so I prefer to keep the array separated.

Here the code:

```
func creaListaCanzoni(){
        var tot = 0
        var a = 0
        for _ in stride(from: 0, to: titoliA.count , by: 1) {
            let voce = VociMontagna(titolo: titoliA[a], artista: artistaA[a])
            listaCanzoni.append(voce)
            a = a + 1
            tot = tot + 1
            print("Tot: \(a)--Nome: \(listaCanzoni[a].nomeTesto)")
        }
    }
```

here the structure:

```
import UIKit

struct VociMontagna {
    let titolo : String
    let artista : String
}
```

[image]

Comment: If `listaCanzoni` is empty to begin with, then based on your logic, it should throw an error since you are incrementing the accessing index before accessing it. If you move your print statement to before the indexes are incremented, the error should go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's unclear why you're keeping this data split up. 800 records is pretty small. Maintaining over 40 arrays seems very complicated.

Your mistake is that you're counting too high. The last index is `titoliA.count - 1`. The indexes start at zero. Instead of this line:

```
for _ in stride(from: 0, to: titoliA.count , by: 1) {
```

You mean this:

```
for a in titolaA.indices {
```

The whole function would look like this:

```
func creaListaCanzoni(){
    for a in titolaA.indices {
        let voce = VociMontagna(titolo: titoliA[a], artista: artistaA[a])
        listaCanzoni.append(voce)
        print("Tot: \(a)--Nome: \(listaCanzoni[a].nomeTesto)")
    }
}
```

That said, if you do need to merge two arrays (and I recommend you don't; just store them as a single array of structs), the better tool would be this:

```
let listaCanzoni = zip(titoliA, artistaA).map(VociMontagna.init)
```

This combines the two arrays and makes structs out them in a single step.